# Tag dropdown not showing

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface

I've edited a few tags on Meta, and it appears that the tag dropdown isn't always working.  I then end up creating new tags, when I might have chosen an old one.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/retag-autocomplete-fails-until-you-remove-and-restore-focus-to-the-tag-box

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a caching problem with the jQuery files that run a lot of the AJAX on the sites. You can test this by trying to click the Flag link on a post and see if you get the red menu pop up. If not, you should try and clear you browser cache and initiate a hard refresh on your browser. That should clear it up.

Comment: I just tested it, got the red menu, but when I added a tag I didn't get the dropdown.  It might be Firefox that's the problem, I only started using it because of the bug (now fixed) here, and then I wanted to use the auto-refresh, but it's kind of a pain.